# How to create jenkins admin user later?

Tags: jenkins

[image]

I clicked continue as admin, so user not created, later there is no admin user option when I logged in. How to set that?

Comment: did the answer help or answer your problem? Pls consider Upvote and or Answered. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, if you have a skipped that installation step, you have also not changed any of the default configuration for Global Security, Authentication, etc.

If you do a basic install, the default security (see `{JENKINS_URL}/configureSecurity/` ) settings (as of LTS 2.222.1) are:

**Authentication**
Security Realm
(o) Jenkins own user database

**Authorization**
Strategy
(o) Logged-in users can do anything

In effect, any new user your create (see `{JENKINS_URL}/securityRealm/` ), Create User ( `{JENKINS_URL}/securityRealm/addUser` ) is by default an **admin**.

In order to restrict access, you must configure Authorization to one of:

- Matrix-based security
- Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy

Those options require [Matrix Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth/) plugin. For more information, review Jenkins Security on [the site](https://www.jenkins.io/security/), or [the book](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/security/).

There are [additional plugins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search?sort=relevance&categories=adminTools&labels=&view=Tiles&page=1&query=security) which may provide more granular [user mgmt](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search/?labels=user), [security](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search/?labels=security) or [user/security](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search/?labels=user&?labels=users) control; [Matrix Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth/)(mentioned), [Role-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/), [Folder-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/folder-auth/) come to mind.

[image: Global security screenshot]

Comment: So is it possible to add an "admin" account after the fact?